# Which Muscle Groups to Work Out Together

Tags: exercise, workout-routines

I'm working on my upper body and have singled out chest, flys, biceps, triceps, back, and shoulder.  If I wanted to exercise two groups each time I go to the gym, which pairings are best?  I have two thoughts.  One, it might be best to group muscles that have the most overlap, so chest/flys, biceps/triceps, back/shoulder.  Then they would get rest and get worked out hard each time.  But, I'm not sure if this would exhaust them too much or be at risk for injury.  Two, I would group them with very little overlap, for example chest/bicep, flys/shoulder, tricep/back.  Then I would be working separate muscles each time.  But, they may not get the rest they need.

Answer (score 2):

**A thousand mindless repetitions of an inefficient movement pattern is both a sign of absolute commitment and ignorance.**

I understand your question. My answer?

**Don't** focus your training on inefficient movement patterns by using dumbles and barbells to train each muscle separately. You will lose your ability to move efficiently, and you will create a body that is weak and ragged.

**Rather** focus on quality movement patterns and try to create a link between LOAD and MOVEMENT. Try to always move in all 3 dimensions. Try to make your training as fun and provocative as possible and avoid a boring routine of 2D exercises.

If you want to explore this kind of exercise and training I strongly advice you to take a look at these websites:

- http://www.viprfit.com/
- http://movnat.com/
- http://www.marksdailyapple.com/primal-blueprint-fitness/

Comment: I like your response, but the websites listed seem to be all product based.  I would recommend looking at http://startingstrength.com/ and like sites that offer free info/advice for full body free weight workouts.